# WordPress Customiser Sub Sections

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to create a sub section within the customiser options in WordPress, so i have a new section called Typography and i want to make sub sections inside that which will be Heading 1, Heading 2 etc... those should open out into their own set of controls. However i have been looking through the codex and cant seem to find a way to link those menus up, any ideas?

Below is the normal code for adding a section but adding a new one doesnt seem to have a option for attaching it to the parent? Ive tried a few variations of the code below without any luck, all i get is 2 typography menus on the main menu.

EDIT: Still having no luck, i read in the codex about a option for panels but cant seem to implement it.

i am using the code below, its just a simplified version of the code to make sure i have it right. I assume a section goes into the panel and the settings and control go into the section. Using this [codex](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/07/08/customizer-improvements-in-4-0/)

```
// ADD PANEL
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'typography_panel', array(
'priority'       => 10,
'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
'theme_supports' => '',
'title'          => 'Typography',
'description'    => 'contains options for all font settings on the website.',
) );

// ADD SECTION TO GO INTO PANEL
$wp_customize->add_section( 'heading_1', array(
'priority'       => 20,
'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
'theme_supports' => '',
'title'          => 'H1 Options',
'description'    => 'all options for heading 1 font.',
'panel'  => 'typography_panel',
) );

// ADD SETTINGS
// Selector Background - Highlighting
$wp_customize->add_setting(
        'typography_highlight_background_h1',
        array(
        'default' => '#333948',
        'sanitize_callback' => '',
    ) );

// ADD CONTROLS
// Highlight Background for Browser
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control( 
        $wp_customize, 'typography_highlight_background_h1', 
        array(
        'label'      => __( 'Highlight Background', 'typography_highlight_background_h1' ),
        'section'    => 'heading_1',
        'settings'   => 'typography_highlight_background_h1',
) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`add_setting`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting) and [`add_control`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control). Sub-sections can be added by passing the name of the section as an argument to `add_control`.

Comment: i did add the setting and control for a option i wanted in the sub section but that only made it appear on the main menu so i end up with 2 menus underneath each other instead of within the previous.